# Little girl goes to Asgard to return Freya's necklace

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, norse-gods

This is a long shot, but does anyone happen to know what this children's book is?

I'm not 100% sure about any of the following details, but here they are.

A little girl went up to Asgard, the home of the Norse gods, to return the goddess Freya's necklace, or possibly to steal it.  I think the little girl had a coat or scarf or something that was important.  The Asgard incident may have been just a side issue in a book that was mainly about something else.

Asgard was at the top of a huge cliff, or a wall as high as a huge cliff, and things were hauled up and down in baskets.

I have no idea of the date or place, I'm afraid; I live in the UK, and the book's not brand new, but that's as much as I know.  I've always read a lot of second-hand books.

There was one more specific thing.  A giant or something kept coming to Asgard and making demands.  He demanded a long list of things, ending in "and the Most Beautiful Freya's hand in marriage".  The gods told him to go away.  He went away and came back with a new list of demands, ending in "and the Most Beautiful Freya's hand in marriage".  He got sent away again, and came back with yet another lot of demands, ending in "and the Most Beautiful Freya's hand in marriage".  Somebody said drily to somebody else, "I'm beginning to see a pattern here".  I think they eventually got rid of him by craftiness, maybe he didn't really want Freya, he only wanted to impress people, or something like that.

Comment: Asking for Freya's hand in marriage is almost a trope in the Eddas. :)  I can recall an ogre asking for that in exchange for returning Thor's hammer, and a giant in exchange for building a wall...

Comment: The necklace is presumably [Brísingamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%ADsingamen).